# How can I stretch a DIV to 100%, without streching its auto-width parent element?

Tags: html, css, width

Given a DIV with several inner-DIVs:

```
<div id="parent">
 <div id="a"></div>
 <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

All DIVs are to have the same width, whereas it should be the width of the broadest DIV. The parent element has no explicit width.

How can I achieve that?

I thought `width: 100%` would do it, but it will stretch the parent element to window size.

Sketch:

```
################
#**************#
#*aaaaaaaaaaaa*#
#**************#
#*********     #
#*bbbbbbb*     #
#*********     #
################
```

should be

```
################
#**************#
#*aaaaaaaaaaaa*#
#**************#
#**************#
#*bbbbbbb     *#
#**************#
################
```

# represents the parent DIV, which does not fill the whole window.

Comment: The title is a bit misleading, you want to stretch form elements, not a `DIV`. You'll need to use some Javascript if you want to apply logic (stretching to the widest, but not necessarily the width of the parent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, this type of CSS related question is perfect for the SO sister site [DocType](http://doctype.com), which focuses on CSS and website design.

As for your problem, divs are block level elements and therefore stretch to all given space. If this is not happening, it means that there is something else overriding this. For a quick fix, add the following:

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
}
```

And it might fix your situation. If it does not, then you'll have some conflicts in you CSS somewhere and by maybe giving some code or a more specific example, we might be able to help more. Again, though, as detailed in the SO FAQ, DocType is more suited for questions like this.

Comment: You're right. It wasn't the inner DIV with streched the parent DIV. It was the parent element itself, which itself is always full size. I should have known that...

Answer (score -2):

A div is generally stretched based on its contents. To get the two inner divs to have the same width, specify width as 50% and float one on the left of the other. Moreover, use a clear:both on the outer div.

please take a look at this great resource as well :

http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/

Comment: The DIVs are not side-by-side, but one below the other.

Comment: Then, you can use float left on all internal divs. However, there has to be something that has a particular width, either that is relevant to the browser viewport or you use absolute values for your width. Else, you need to set the height and work on percentages based on the height, for each div.

Comment: I'm not sure, that you read the question. Maybe you should rephrase your answer (and comment). But I think that "float" will not be part of any solution, as it will not affect the size but the position of the elements.

Comment: The float is just a way to have your divs one on top of the other. Do you read my answers ?

Comment: DIVs are one on top of the other by default. I don't need float for that.

Comment: No, they are not. You may specify that somewhere, but it's not what happens by default. In your code, by default, one is inside the other. How they are stretched inside your external div, depends on your css. To do one on top of the other the proper way, you will need to use float.